# what is the port range of rpcbind in linux?

Tags: linux, rpc

What is the port range for rpcbind services? does it have a specific port range or it is using ports range 0-1023?

Thanks.
 Mahmoud

Answer (score 1):

portmapper listens on the well known port of 111 to provide information about other rpc services (which register can can have varied port bindings).

```
$ getent services  sunrpc
sunrpc                111/tcp portmapper rpcbind
```

Comment: Note [portmapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmap) also operates on UDP.